# How to load a recyclerView from 2 different spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I have to do a clothes shop app and I'm trying to do filter search with 2 spinners and a recyclerView. The problem is that I don't know how to filter it. The data is downloaded from firebase. The thing is that I want to be a dynamic recycler so if I choose one of the selections I want to be seen the request. So my problem is that I don't know how to know which of the two spinners are used. Both spinners must work individually, but they compliment each other.

Here is my code.

```
String txtBrand,txtKind;
Spinner spinBrand,spinKind;
RecyclerView rv;
List<String>Brands;
List<Producto> productlist;
AdapterAllProducts adapterAllProducts;
public DatabaseReference mReference;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_fragment, container, false);
    spinMarca=v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerBrand);
    spinTipo=v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKind);
    rv=v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    Brands= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.brands));
    mReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Product");
    spinBrand.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            txtBrand = Brands.get(i);
            loadRecycler(txtBrand);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}


public void loadRecycler(final String Marca){
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    productslist= new ArrayList<>();
    adapterAllProducts = new AdapterAllProducts(productslist,getActivity());
    adapterAllProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Product prod = productslist.get(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
            String pid = prod.getPid();
            String name = prod.getName();
            String desc = prod.getDescription();
            String ref = prod.getReference();
            float pri = (float)prod.getPrize();
            int cant = prod.getQuantity();
            String brand = prod.getBrand();
            Preferencias.setPid(getActivity(),pid);
            Preferencias.setName(getActivity(),nombre);
            Preferencias.setPrize(getActivity(),pre);
            Preferencias.setReference(getActivity(),ref);
            Preferencias.setDesc(getActivity(),desc);
            Preferencias.setQuantity(getActivity(),cant);
            Preferencias.setBrand(getActivity(),brand);

            Fragment fragment = new ProductsFragment();
            FragmentManager ManagerUser = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transactionUser = ManagerUser.beginTransaction();
            transactionUser.replace(R.id.contentfragment,fragmentuser);
            transactionUser.commit();

        }
    });
    rv.setAdapter(adapterAllProducts);

    Query q = mReference.orderByChild("brand").equalTo(brand);
    q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            productoslist.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
            ) {
                Product product = Snapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                productslist.add(product);
            }
            adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}}
```

I apologize for my English. It's not my mother language. If anyone can help me with this I will be very grateful with them.

Comment: Hi, why do you want to differentiate between the 2 spinners? just use the data fetched from the firebase/local list(in case you have all the data with you) and pass the list your RecyclerView adatpter and notify it.

Comment: The thing is that I want to have the option to search with one of the filters or both of them. So I need to know wich one has been selected to show all the products that have that token in common. For example I want to have the option to search "Nike" and see all the products from them and If in the second spinner I select "shoes" I want to show all the shoes with the token Nike

Comment: @AsthaGarg Also I want to have the option to search "shoes" and see all the shoes that I have in my database

Comment: You can use String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); to fetch the selected text from the spinner and pass as request to your server/ DB query.

Comment: @AsthaGarg That´s what I have done. But only works for a single one of them. It´s that why I have to know wich one is used

Comment: So to read data from both the spinners, you need to use String text1 = mySpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString() & String text2 = mySpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString() whenever there's any change in any spinner or when user dismisses your filter popup.

Comment: Basic idea: read from both the spinners when user tries to change his filter. This way just add the check for null/blank/Default text shown as 0th index of spinner

Comment: @AsthaGarg I understand what you say... Let me try it.

Comment: Sure. I'm ready to help any further as well :)

Comment: @AsthaGarg I think it works. Well at least during the testing with a few products. I don´t know what will happen when I have more products in the databes. But by know it works

Comment: If it is working with few products, it will also work for many because this solution is reliable not a hack. Also, please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to read from both the `spinners` when user tries to change his filter or when user dismisses your filter popup. This way just add the check for null/blank/Default text shown as 0th index of `spinner`

```
String text1 = mySpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString() 
String text2 = mySpinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()
```